# Opening Lowrance .at5 files in Mac/Linux/Windows

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, bathymetry

I have some bathymetry data in Lowrance .at5 format. I would like to read those data to my computer and process it (convert it into point cloud etc). Is there any software available to do so? Or is there any Python package to read those data? Or any program?

Comment: Some software store data as text file with custom extension, you could try to open it with a text editor to check if this is the case for .at5 file, if yes you may be able to turn it to a QGIS readable format like csv. Also a quick google search give this Online AT5 Text Viewer that you may try... (https://filext.com/file-extension/AT5)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I've seen for the Lowrance AT5 format is the [Reefmaster Software](https://reefmaster.com.au/). If you can get your data in Lowrance USR Format, [GPSBabel](https://www.gpsbabel.org/) and [GPS Visualizer](https://www.gpsvisualizer.com/) can convert it for you.

Comment: I'm not able to load at5 to reefmaster. I can take at5 output format from it.